# Asymptotic behavior of $I(\lambda) = \int_0^\infty f(x) \sin(\lambda x) dx$ as $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, asymptotics

This question comes from here ([Does this integral have a closed form or asymptotic expansion? $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\beta u)}{1+u^\alpha} du$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207869/does-this-integral-have-a-closed-form-or-asymptotic-expansion-int-0-infty-f)) and has haunted me a while.

Some observations

- stationary phase does not work (at least I can't figure it out), because the phase function $x$ does not have a stationary point to expand around.
- at $x = 0$, there is no oscillation, but integrand is $0$. So the integration is from regions away from $x=0$, but those regions are "packed" with oscillations as $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$.
- $\int_0^1 1/x dx$ itself does not converge, but with $\sin(\lambda x)$ multiplied, we have the celebrated $sinc$ function. What's more, the integration $I(\lambda) = \pi/2$: a small, finite number **independent** of $\lambda$.
- Numerical results suggest the $1/\lambda$ behavior applies to many cases - details below.

Numerical experiment was done on 6 functions (reminder, $I(\lambda) = \int_0^1 f(x) sin(\lambda x)$). The $\textsf{label as}$ corresponds to the legend in the figure.

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \quad \textsf{label as "s"}
$$

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x} \quad \textsf{label as "1"}
$$

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} \quad \textsf{label as "2"}
$$
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^3} \quad \textsf{label as "3"}
$$
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^4} \quad \textsf{label as "4"}
$$

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{e^x} \quad \textsf{label as "e", for this case we have} \quad I = \frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda^2}
$$

The figure is below (the two solid lines are for references). It can be seen 5 function converges to the $1/\lambda$ line, the behavior for the $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$ is different, but we can focus on it later. Any suggestion?

[image: summary]

Comment: This type of integral is extremely close to those encountered in Fourier transforms, defined by $F(q) = F[f(x)] = \int_{-\infty} ^\infty f(x) \exp(i q x) dx$, where you replaced $q$ with $\lambda$ and you're trying to look at the tail when $F(q)$ when $q \rightarrow \infty$. The tail is dependent on the form of $f(x)$. For instance, $f(x) = exp(-x)$ leads to lorrentian profiles (like your case) and $f(x) = exp(-x^2)$ leads to gaussian profiles.

Comment: point is, that the method of stationary phase applies in this cases. There is no reason why it shouldn't (it is just the method of stationary points for BOUNDARY VALUES). The difference between $1/\sqrt{x}$ and the rest is due to the singular behaviour at $x=0$..

Comment: @MGirard Thank you for the input. Many Fourier or Laplace transforms (or their inverse) give complex integrations that can only be analyzed asymptotically. The examples you gave have analytical solutions, but I was wondering more general cases where there are no explicit solutions.

Comment: @tired But how to proceed? Expanding the phase function $h(x) = x$ around $x = 0$ just gives $x = h(x) = h(0) + h'(0)(x-0) + h''(0)(x-0)^2/2 + \cdots = x $, that's why  in the question I said it can not be expanded.

Comment: If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, then the Riemann–Lebesgue lemma implies your integral tends to zero as $\lambda \to \infty$. If $f$ is differentiable and has (Lebesgue-)integrable derivative, you can put a more explicit decay rate on ($O(1/\lambda)$, for example). If $f$ is not Lebesgue-integrable, you can even have growth: for example, $f(x)=(\log{x})/x$ has integral that grows like $\log{\lambda}$.

Comment: the minimum of the pase function is just $x=0$

Comment: Putting aside exceptional cases, you an perform a partial integration where you repeatedly integrate the factor $$\sin(\lambda x)\rightarrow -\frac{\cos(\lambda x)}{\lambda}\rightarrow -\frac{\sin(\lambda x)}{\lambda^2}$$ etc.

Comment: I would try to split it up in cases depending on the behavior close to $x=0$. It looks like we have something like (assuming the integral exists): 1) if $\lim_{x\to 0} xf(x) = C$ then $\sim C\pi/2$. 2) if $\lim_{x\to 0}xf(x) = 0$ then $\sim \frac{1}{\lambda}$. 3) if $\lim_{x\to 0} xf(x) = \infty$ then $\sim\frac{f(1/\lambda)}{\lambda}$.

Comment: @tired Your suggestion leads to $\int f(z) e^{i \lambda z} dz = f(0) \int e^{i \lambda z} dz = f(0) \frac{e^ {i \lambda \infty}-1}{i \lambda}$, take imaginary part gives $f(0) \frac{{1 - \cos (\lambda \infty)}}{\lambda} $. This is close to  $1/\lambda$, but how to deal with the denominator?

Comment: @Taozi first option: use distributions (maybe a bit over the top). second option deform your path of integration so that it goes along the positive imaginary axis and show that possible residue contributions can be neglected. third option: introduce a small damping parameter $i\lambda t \rightarrow t(i \lambda-\epsilon)$ and let $\epsilon$ go to zero in the end (physicist style)

Comment: @Chappers Hi, how do you derive $\int_0^{\infty} x^{-1} \log x \sin (\lambda x) dx \sim \log\lambda$? Shouldn't the LHS diverges and always equal to $\infty$?

Comment: @Taozi $x^{s}$ is decreasing for $s<0$, and that means that $\int_0^{\infty} x^s \sin{\lambda x} \, dx$ converges for $-2<s<0$ by the usual argument about splitting it up into an alternating series. One can then evaluate this integral using Cauchy's Theorem and the Gamma-function, and differentiate under the integral and evaluate at $s=-1$ to get something like $-\frac{\pi}{2}(\gamma+\log{\lambda})$.